# Redeploy web application to OpenShift Tomcat 7 cartridge with Eclipse OpenShift Tools?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, openshift, eclipse-kepler

I've been able to use Eclipse OpenShift Tools to create a web application and deploy it to a Tomcat 7 cartridge on OpenShift.

How does the (re)development cycle continue from there on. For instance, if I edit `index.html` and click on `Restart app on OpenShift` (or `Run on Server`) these changes do not show up in `http://<app>-<domain>.rhcloud.com/index.hmtl`.

So how can I redeploy the web application to OpenShift from inside Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit your changes in your git repository and then do a git push to deploy them to your application

Comment: Is there any way to deploy from inside Eclipse without commit. I don't want to put my source code and binaries onto OpenShift, just the binaries.

Comment: If you don't want to use the OpenShift git repo, then you need to do something like this: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399740-How-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-WAR-and-EAR-files-onto-your-OpenShift-gear-using-the-java-cartridges

Comment: Yep, but in specific relation to this question: the OpenShift tooling from Eclipse does not seem to allow this from inside the IDE (at least I have not found anything it so far.) Looks as if I need to deploy from the command line even during development then.

Comment: You could also try using the JRebel cartridge here: https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-jrebel-cartridge , It's really more for development than doing production use I believe, but should do what you are asking.

Comment: Thx, will give that one also a try.

Answer (score 0):

You must click right button of mouse on your project in eclipse and select Team -> Commit... Then in openned window write commit message and press button "Commit and Push". then in servers tab click right button of mouse on started server and select Publish. It will works.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this matter, but this sounds to me like adding source to the source control system. Can you elaborate situation a bit?

Comment: @Miki It may be that committing the source code also deploys in this case (deploy by git). However, I don't want to put my source code and binaries onto OpenShift, just the binaries.

Comment: @Drux Oh, I'm sorry. I don't seen your question below answer before. In your case I don't know how to do what you want.